# Adding the Classic Editor to a Gutenberg Block Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

NOTE:  Here is a video that helps explain my question:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c3pS-j8yq75GAwGDrrMMh9X7fDrCKV5R/view?pli=1

I am creating a custom post type that includes a set of blocks as a template.  My basic code looks like this:

```
function register_article_post_type(){
    $post_settings = array(
      'label' => 'Articles',
      'public' => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'template_lock' => 'all',
      'template' => array(
        array( 'core/heading',
            array(
                'placeholder' => 'Add Categories Heading...',
                'className' => 'tour_categories_heading'
            )
        ),
        )
    );
    register_post_type('article', $post_settings);
}
```

That will create a Custom Post Type called Articles which has a singular Heading block.  The thing is, I don't want a heading block, I want the Classic Editor block.

But I can't figure out how to add it.  I can easily change the Heading block to a different block (say the paragraph block) if I change `array( 'core/heading',` to `array( 'core/paragraph',`.

But when I check the code in Gutenberg for the name of the Classic editor, nothing shows up.  As such, I cannot figure out how to add a Classic editor to the custom post type.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try `core/freeform` - should be the slug for the classic editor block

Comment: Worked for me! Note that is says freeFORM, not freeDOM, which is how I read it the first time. Obv there is no freedom block (yet) :)